# How to get back to normal after ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase screw-up?

Tags: ecryptfs

After my laptop lost power last night, I logged on today to find my encrypted home directory not mounted.  Since I have recently changed my login password, I used 
  ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
to rewrap my passphrase, using my old login/ecrypt passphrase, and entering my new login/ecrypt passphrase.  This had worked in the past.  I logged out, and logged back in, and, no good home directory.  I had forgotten about ecryptfs-mount-private, so I tried it again, but this time the screen went black and it just sat there for a while.  I stupidly then just turned the laptop off.  Then restarted, logged in, and this time tried ecryptfs-mount-private.  I get:
Enter your login passphrase:
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect
...though I know I'm entering the correct passphrase.

When I did sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
It did indeed find it: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxxxxx] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted read-only at [/tmp/ecryptfs.vZCfaWzw].

Ok, so what do I do next?  Should I go into full recovery mode and copy the found directory to another disk, and start from scratch?  Or should I try:
ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
...hoping that I can give it the original mount password, and then my login password again.
Or???

I'm a in a bit of a panic, and am worried I'm going to screw things up more.  Any help would be most appreciated!  The man pages are very terse and unclear.